# How to create a random list of doubles (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter

```
List<AudioWaveBar> bars = [];

               

                var list = List<double>.generate(100, (i) => i as double)..shuffle();

                for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {

                  bars.add(AudioWaveBar(
                      heightFactor: list[i],
                      color: widget.podcast.percentPlayed >= ((i + 1).toDouble() / list.length.toDouble())
                          ? AppTheme.greenStart
                          : Colors.white10
                  ));                }
```

I need to have a list of random doubles only (from 0 to 1), but random function doesn't add the numbers to a list and generate function only accepts int numbers that can't be casted. Any help? thanks!

Comment: Do you want a list where each element is a random `double` in the range [0, 1), or do you want a list of `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...]` that is shuffled? If the former, you can do: `var random = Random(); var list = List<double>.generate(100, (_) => random.nextDouble());` or `var random = Random(); var list = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) random.nextDouble()];`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply. Indeed I only need doubles between 0 to 1. I tried both of your solution, but I have still the error message "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast". When I try to add a heightFactor, the code seems to think that my double is an int, and therefore crashes. I'm not sure why it confuses the double type with the int type. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The function `Random().nextDouble()` generates a random double between 0 and 1.
So just by specifying a max value u can get what u want, like so :

```
int maxValue = 1000;
var list = List<double>.generate(100, (i) => Random().nextDouble() * maxValue)..shuffle();
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I forgot to mention I would like  a list from 0 to 1 only and this list needs to be shuffled. (I will edit my post to clarify!) :)

Comment: No worries, just remove the `* maxValue` and u r good to go.

Comment: I tried the solution, and I think it does create a list, but when I test the code, during the loop, the heightFactor sends an error and tells me that the number I gave is an int that is not a subtype of double (although when I code, It recognizes that it is a double). Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe the `heightFactor` requires an `int` not a `double`, and u r passing a `double` so it throws an exception.

Comment: Hm Here is the description of the heightFactor: "{required double heightFactor}  Type: double  
heightFactor is the height of the bar based. It is percentage rate of widget height.
If it's set to 0.5, then it will be 50% height from the widget height.
heightFactor of bar must be between 0 to 1. Or There will be side effect."

If I try to give it an int, it tells me that it can't accept the number also.

Comment: Weird, can u post the error message ?

Comment: Oh never mind, I found the error, it was from a function above that I didn't use but the code still read it :D Thanks for helping me I really appreciate it!

Comment: Nice, and u're welcome, good luck with your project.